# Special characters are converting into some other type while loading into ms sql from flat file source using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to load data like "7704ó " into ms sql table through SSIS from flat file. But after loading the data what apper in the table is like "7704¢ ". I tried converting the code page from 1251 to 65001(UTF-8) and changing the datatype to WSTR type but still no use and flooded with the error messages. Please anyone help resolving this.

Comment: Maybe you need to change the collation of your table to match the incoming data.

Comment: I tried changing to UTF-8 collation,can youplease suggest any collation that suits my situation ?.

Comment: I have no idea.  I guess it would be whatever collation natively has the characters you are trying to get into your table.

Comment: What is the datatype of the target column? NVARCHAR (vs VARCHAR) will hold all characters. Use `UNICODE(YourField,5,1))` function to inspect what that numeric unicode representation is of that last character. It might be correct in the database but not showing on your client correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First, is the destination column char/varchar or nchar/nvarchar? For char/varchar, the database collation decides the code page that will be used by the server for example. As a result, if the code page used by the server doesn't contain the character that you are importing then you will get gibberish or it might translate to something else.

So start from the source? How was the file produced? Is it from a different SQL Server database or a different product?